# Is there any way that i can give these ADB commands in a single-line?

Tags: adb, crash-reports

D:\Users >adb shell

msmnile_gvmq:/ # cd /data/anr

msmnile_gvmq:/data/anr # ls

anr_2023-03-15-14-41-51-747

I tried like this,
D:\Users >adb shell cd /data/anr ls

/system/bin/sh: cd: bad substitution

but i got this...

I should get the anr logs as expected. i.e(anr_2023-03-15-14-41-51-747)

Can anybody help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
adb shell ls /data/anr

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
adb shell "cd /data/anr && ls"
```

Comment: That is the proper one, or just with a semicolon; . +1